# How to configurate msmtprc for each user

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, sendmail, php

- I have a Ubuntu server with nginx and php-fpm;
- Need to configure msmtp for each user to work with sites.
  The manual says:

> You need to have a .msmtprc file in the home of every users who want
> to send mail (for example if you want to send mails as root), or
> alternatively you can use a system wide /etc/msmtprc

1. I setup msmtp
2. Create configuration file in /etc/msmtprc

But I can't understand how to configure sending for each user.
I understand that need to put each msmtprc with mail settings for specific user in /home/~username/
right?

And how to configure php.ini, that single user site sends mail form his domain?
In manual nothing says about msmtprc setup for each single user.
Man pointed out the example:

```
sendmail_path = /usr/bin/msmtp-t-i-a username
```

I understand this for use a specific config. And what keys you need to put or remove for individual configs work?

UPD:
There example script which create users (may it help)
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/2457864/addsite.sh

Answer (score 1):

Found solution [here](http://scottboms.com/2009/05/msmtp-and-virtual-hosts/)
But in php-fpm configs need change:

```
  php_admin_value sendmail_path "/usr/bin/msmtp -a domain1 -t"
```

to

```
  php_admin_value[sendmail_path] = /usr/bin/msmtp -a domain1 -t
```

And all works fine